# What does "Please wrap your loss computation in a zero argument `lambda`." means?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I made a code for adding L2 loss to the main loss function:

```
def add_l2(model, penalty=0.001):
    for layer in model.layers:
        if "conv" in layer.name:
            model.add_loss(penalty * tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(layer.trainable_variables[0])))
    return

## training
@tf.function
def train_one_step(model, x, y, optimizer):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        logits = model(x, training=True)
        loss = _criterion(y_true=y, y_pred=logits)

        add_l2(model, 0.001)
        loss += sum(model.losses)

    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
    return loss, logits
```

And when I started to train, I had a error like below:

> **ValueError**: Expected a symbolic Tensors or a callable for the loss value. Please wrap your loss computation in a zero argument `lambda`.

What does it mean of this error? And How can I treat it?

Comment: A zero-argument lambda looks like this: `model.add_loss(lambda: penalty * tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(layer.trainable_variables[0])))
 `

Comment: @NPE Wow, it works well, thank you!  If you don't mind, could you explain why I should use lambda function in add_loss()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loss is referencing a variable of one of the model's layers (`layer.trainable_variables[0]`) and so there is need to wrap your loss in a zero-argument lambda so as to make it callable.
`model.add_loss(lambda: penalty * tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(layer.trainable_variables[0])`

For more detail check it out in the official documentation [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#add_loss)

Comment: This does solve the error but the gradients do not seem to be propogated properly: the loss never goes down. I'm using something like `model.add_loss(lambda: tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(embedding_layer.weights[0])))`. Any tips? The actual loss is more complicated but even this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue and found a solution.

**The Problem:** When calling `add_loss` outside of the Layer's `call` function the `losses` attribute doesn't get reset automatically.
Hence, with each iteration, it accumulates more and more loss tensors. This is hardly noticeable and probably messes up the gradient.

**The solution**, if you want to add a loss term outside of the Layer's `call` function, is to first **clear the `_callable_losses` list manually** and then add the loss term wrapped in a lambda function.

Changing your example to:

```
def add_l2(model, penalty=0.001):
    # clear the losses list of model
    model._callable_losses.clear()

    for layer in model.layers:
        if "conv" in layer.name:
            model.add_loss(lambda: penalty * tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(layer.trainable_variables[0])))
    return
```

should solve the issue. Of course, this also removes any losses added before. If this needs to be prevented, single entries in `_callable_losses` can be removed via `model._callable_losses.pop(idx)`